# Unlock second screen Objective c

Tags: objective-c, screen, fullscreen, unlock

i have an app which lock screen and now i try it with multiple screens. I don't know to unlock the second screen. 
here is how i unlock the second screen :

```
if([[NSScreen screens] count] > 1){
    // Draw a new window to fill the screen
    NSScreen *screen;
    NSRect screenRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, screen.frame.size.width , screen.frame.size.height);

    NSWindow *secondaryMonitorWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:screenRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask  backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered  defer:NO  screen:screen];


    [secondaryMonitorWindow.contentView exitFullScreenModeWithOptions:nil];


}
```

i successfully unlock the first screen but not the second, if someone can help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if someone needs i fixed it with the following code :

.m

```
[windowArray insertObject:self.window atIndex:0];

        //if we have many screens
        NSRect screenRect;
        NSArray *screenArray = [NSScreen screens];
        for (NSInteger index = 1; index < [screenArray count]; index++)

        {

            NSScreen *screen = [screenArray objectAtIndex: index];

            screenRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, screen.frame.size.width , screen.frame.size.height);
            NSWindow *window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:screenRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO screen:screen];

            [window.contentView setWantsLayer:YES];
            window.contentView.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor blackColor].CGColor;
            [window.contentView enterFullScreenMode:[[NSScreen screens] objectAtIndex:index] withOptions:nil];


            [windowArray addObject:window];

        }
```

Don't forget to add in .h

```
NSMutableArray *windowArray;
```

And to exitFullScreen :

```
for(NSInteger index = 1; index < [windowArray count]; index ++){

            if([[windowArray objectAtIndex:index]contentView].inFullScreenMode){

                [[[windowArray objectAtIndex:index]contentView] exitFullScreenModeWithOptions:nil];

            } 
        }
```